# Tricky limit algebra

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Could someone please help me figure out the following algbera?

I really don't understand *any* of the steps.

$$
 \begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})} \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-(1-x^2)}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2)}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: What about this do you not get? The steps are (in order) multiplying the numerator and denominator by an expression, evaluating the multiplication, simplifying the numerator.

Comment: I don't get how the square root expressions are being used. For example, in the first step, is what's multiplied to the expression equal to 1? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to evaluate the limit in its initial form you end up with $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}=\frac{0}{0}$$
which is an indeterminate form.

To get rid of this indetermination, you simply need to multiply the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the numerator, which is $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

After making some simplifications, the $x$ which caused the denominator's tending to $0$ as $x\to0$ causing the indetermination gets deleted. Now the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{0}{2}=0$$

Comment: I understand why we do, it's just how that I don't get.  For example, why is it that we use conjugate at the numerator but a different expression at the denominator? Are you telling me those two equal to one?

Comment: If you multiply the numerator and the denominator of a fraction by the same number or expression $k\leq 0$, the fraction does not change because $\frac{k}{k}=1$. Also, the multiplying by the conjugate is a standard step for limits which involve expressions with roots. Roots go away after applying the identity $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ and usually the terms which zero out the denominator go away too. After all those steps, the limit is easily computable.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have given aren't really to do with the limits at all, it's just a question about manipulating the algebraic expression.

The first step essentially is "multiplying by one", probably our most useful tool in manipulating fractions. It is not hard to see that $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1$, and clearly anything multiplied by one remains the same (due to 1 being the identity element for the binary operation of scalar multiplication). But why $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

The term $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is said to be the "conjugate" of $1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and their product is said to be the difference of two squares (i.e. $(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})=(1^2-(\sqrt{1-x^2})^2=(1-(1-x^2))$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares for more information on this.

So we have chosen this product to engineer a numerator without a square root in it.

It is clear that multiplying out the numerator gives us our desired form $$\frac{(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x(1+\sqrt{x^2})} = \frac{1-(1-x^2)}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$

Now, we can simplify the numerator $1-(1-x^2)=-(-x^2)=x^2$, this gives us the fraction $$\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ as required.

Comment: Haha, I see now. Wow, how did I not see this. Thanks for your answer!